# Postgres13 : LOG: could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device

Tags: postgresql

I have a centos 7.9 machine and I am using postgres13. I have a program on one drive writing to Postgres DB files on another drive. They used to be on the same drive. Since I have moved the program, I have seen the app crash after the Postgres service crashes. It appears that Postgres complains of no memory.

```
2023-08-03 07:13:24.555 CEST [19273] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_23048.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
```

I have been reading up on this error. At this stage I don't know if:

1. Another program is taking up the space temporarily. At this stage I don't think this is so.
2. A large sql query is causing this issue.
3. A large sql query and the fact that binary is on a different drive to the DB
4. If the app is at fault. It is mattermost. I haven't had any issue since I moved the binary to a different drive,

My question is, could this be caused by the item 3 above? Also can I alter  settings in the .conf file to both remedy this problem  and acquire more debug data relating to this.

This is the rest of the log

```
    sudo cat /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/log/postgresql-Thu.log
2023-08-03 02:14:02.319 CEST [19263] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
2023-08-03 02:14:02.320 CEST [19263] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-08-03 02:14:02.323 CEST [19263] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-08-03 02:14:02.330 CEST [19263] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-08-03 02:14:02.336 CEST [19266] LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2023-08-02 21:41:18 CEST
2023-08-03 02:14:02.517 CEST [19266] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-08-03 02:14:02.523 CEST [19266] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1B80C1E0
2023-08-03 02:14:02.524 CEST [19266] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1B812A70: wanted 24, got 0
2023-08-03 02:14:02.524 CEST [19266] LOG:  redo done at 0/1B812A38
2023-08-03 02:14:02.571 CEST [19263] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-08-03 07:10:14.385 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_23048.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:14.362 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:14.363 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:24.482 CEST [19273] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:11:24.485 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_23048.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:24.485 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:24.485 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:11:34.607 CEST [26445] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:12:14.402 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:12:14.402 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:12:24.546 CEST [19273] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:12:24.548 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_23048.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:12:24.549 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:12:24.549 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:12:34.689 CEST [27514] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:13:14.434 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:14.434 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:24.555 CEST [19273] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_23048.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:24.557 CEST [19274] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-08-03 07:13:34.664 CEST [28580] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2023-08-03 07:14:05.961 CEST [19270] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
2023-2023-08-03 07:38:20.160 CEST [26786] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
2023-08-03 07:38:20.160 CEST [26786] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-08-03 07:38:20.166 CEST [26786] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-08-03 07:38:20.178 CEST [26786] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-08-03 07:38:20.186 CEST [26790] LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2023-08-03 07:14:07 CEST
2023-08-03 07:38:20.373 CEST [26790] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-08-03 07:38:20.382 CEST [26790] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1B9ED838
2023-08-03 07:38:20.382 CEST [26790] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1B9F4870: wanted 24, got 0
2023-08-03 07:38:20.382 CEST [26790] LOG:  redo done at 0/1B9F4838
2023-08-03 07:38:20.437 CEST [26786] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Look in the log file for other errors.  It would be very unusual for a process to use up so much temp space that it the stats collector suffers this error, but without that other process also experiencing a similar error itself.

Comment: Hi @jjanes thanks for the tip. I have added the rest of the log file. I see at 2023-08-03 02:14:02.571, that the DB is ready to start receiving connections, and the some time after that the DB complains about insufficient space on the disk. I am not sure what the improper shutdown prior to this log point refers to, and whether it was the previous crash.

Comment: Were you very short on storage to start with?  If you chronically run with only a whisker of free space, well, stop doing that.

Comment: Hi @jjanes, we have about 70 GB free, so I think we should be right with that amount of free memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of disk space in the data directory.

To determine if that's because of PostgreSQL temporary files or not, set `log_temp_files = '10MB'`. Then you will get log messages if that happens.

Temporary files are created in the `base/pgsql_tmp` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL data directory.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe. Much appreciated.